# How to suppress D3 or MetricsGraphics animation while rendering

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the MetricsGraphics library and D3 to draw a curveStep time series plot.  The plot is redrawn when additional data becomes available.

Below is the code, and here is the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/5kbr5mk5/

```
var mydata = [];
var intervalID = setInterval( function addsample() {
var newval = Math.random() * 10;
var mysample = { 
    timestamp: new Date(), 
    value: newval };
mydata.push( mysample );
console.log("sample count: " + mydata.length);
if (mydata.length == 100) clearInterval(intervalID);

MG.data_graphic({
title: "Time Series Plot",
data: mydata,
    interpolate: d3.curveStep,
    chart_type: 'line',
height: 400,
width: 600,
xax_count: 3,
x_accessor: 'timestamp',
y_accessor: 'value',
area: false,
target: '#chart'
});},1000);
```

Where is the strange animation (morphing) coming from as the plot is being updated, and how do I suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `transition_on_update` argument to `false`:

```
var mydata = [];
var intervalID = setInterval( function addsample() {
      var newval = Math.random() * 10;
    var mysample = { 
        timestamp: new Date(), 
        value: newval };
    mydata.push( mysample );
    console.log("sample count: " + mydata.length);
    if (mydata.length == 100) clearInterval(intervalID);

    MG.data_graphic({
    title: "Time Series Plot",
    data: mydata,
        interpolate: d3.curveStep,
        chart_type: 'line',
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    xax_count: 3,
    x_accessor: 'timestamp',
    y_accessor: 'value',
    area: false,
    target: '#chart',
    transition_on_update: false //here's the argument
    });

  },1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5kbr5mk5/16/

Comment: That's freakin' awesome!  I hoped it would be that simple!